# How can I disable past dates in angular p-calendar?

Tags: angular, html, bootstrap-4

I am using [p-calendar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar)

I would like all past dates to be disabled

here is what I have :

```
 <p-calendar formControlName="date" [inline]="true" tabindex="0" [disabledDates]="invalidDates" [disabledDays]="[0,6]"></p-calendar>
```

This is not working, what do I need to change to get the result I want ?

Comment: Set the `minDate` input to the current day

Comment: can you pust it as answer so that I can accept if it works? much better?

Comment: @Kaczkapojebana. By looking at your questions in your profile You have been asking this question (about date) but you have been rewording it 3 to 4 times. Perhaps you need to make your question more specific so that others may help you.

Comment: Ur right but now some one helped what I wanted  works now

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The calendar has a `minDate` input. Just set it to the current date, that way it cannot be lower than today.

In the code:

```
minimumDate = new Date();
```

In the template:

```
<p-calendar formControlName="date" [inline]="true" [minDate]="minimumDate" tabindex="0" [disabledDates]="invalidDates" [disabledDays]="[0,6]"></p-calendar>
```

Comment: If date editing is present, editing the date to a past date, allows choosing past date.

Comment: Is there anything for Time also? Lets say right now its is 14:00 hrs and want to prevent the user from selecting anything before this 14:00 hrs not even 13:59 hrs. Please help. I didnt find anything for mintime.